# Removing attributes in XML with wildcards

Tags: xml, powershell, xml-parsing

I have a bunch of xml files that needs attributes beginning with `name` removed (e.g. `name-first`, `name-last`, `name-middle`). I've tried a few different ways to do this but have not come close.

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "C:\test" -Filter *.xml 

foreach($file in $files){
    $fileXML= [xml](Get-Content $file.FullName -Encoding UTF8)
    #$nameNode1= $fileXML.Body.InnerXML.Contains('name-')
    #$nameNode2= $fileXML.Body.SelectNodes("//*[contains(@name,'')]")
    #$nameNode2= $fileXML.assessmentItem.SelectNodes("//*[local-name()='name-']")

    foreach($name in $nameNode2){
        if($name -like 'name-') {
            $name.ParentNode.RemoveAttribute($name)
        }
    }

    $fileXML.save($fileXML)
}
```

Per request, here is an example XML file:

```
<root>
    <web-app id="app-1" />
    <element id="xt92" name-type="base" name-type-style="default" />
    <elementBody>
        <content name="about-us">content</content>
        <content name="news"><p name-its="default">content</p</content>
    </elementBody>
</root>
```

The outcome should look like this:

```
<root>
    <web-app id="app-1" />
    <element id="xt92" />
    <elementBody>
        <content name="about-us">content</content>
        <content name="news"><p>content</p</content>
    </elementBody>
</root>
```

Comment: `($name -like 'name '` -> `($name -like "name*"`. That's useless unless `$nameNode2` is populated. Are the attributes at the same level or different levels? Could you post a simplified XML structure?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I need to remove the attribute, not replac it. Although I suppose technically I could replace `name-*` with just an empty space and it would work?

Comment: Oh wait, you mean if any attribute matches the `name-` pattern, that entire attribute needs to be removed? not just editing the attribute name?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Correct. If the attribute matches `name-` it should be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to fully figure out how to do this via a loop, however I was able to do this with some regex

$xmlContent.root.InnerXml = $xmlContent.root.InnerXml -replace '(\sname([-a-zA-Z]+.\w*[a-zA-Z0-9-\=:.;\s]+)).+?(\")'

Answer (score 0):

Here is an XSLT 3.0 solution:

```
<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
<xsl:template match="@*[starts-with(name(), 'name-')]"/>
```